# Excel: Not unable to update automatically after trigger

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell A1 which extracts values from a server every *n* seconds, however using the macro below (which is currently used) is not suitable:

```
Dim preVal As String
Dim count As Integer

'Intention is if cell A1 changes, record changes to Column C and Column D
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target = Range("A1") Then
                Call cellchange(Range("A1"))
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub cellchange(ByVal a As Range)
   'If row is empty, filled into that row, if not skip to next one  
    If a.Value <> preVal Then
        count = count + 1
'copy the value of A1 from sheet 1 
        preVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        Cells(count, 4).Value = a.Value
 'copy the values of time of which data change detected       
        Cells(count, 3) = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

In a simplest way, the cell A1 will be updated every few seconds from a server, so I need the macro to be updated/trigger when it detects changes in cell A1 that are not from human input.

Comment: I think this code is not good at all. If there is another code to read and update A1 from the server, why you are not adding such an update procedure to add? Also on the CellChange, using this kind of Preval will make not updating the cell if the new entry is same to the perivous one. It assumes the consecutive values can not be same!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something that really checks if your target cells is updated. usually `application.intersect` are used. Here I am using address property.

```
Dim preVal As String
Dim count As Integer

'Intention is if cell A1 changes, record changes to Column C and Column D
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.address = Range("A1").address Then
                cellchange target 
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub cellchange(ByVal a As Range)
   'If row is empty, filled into that row, if not skip to next one  
    If a.Value <> preVal Then
        count = count + 1
'copy the value of A1 from sheet 1 
        preVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        Cells(count, 4).Value = a.Value
 'copy the values of time of which data change detected       
        Cells(count, 3) = Now
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,
M